# Add array values into map using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array value as a with key:value pair. I wanted to map the same key array values as below format:

```
Expected Output: [abc: 1],[def:2,42,40]
```

Please find my code below:

```
var a = {"abc": 1, "def": 2, "def": 42, "def" : 40};    
var array_keys = new Array();
var array_values = new Array();
for (var key in a) {
    array_keys.push(key);
    array_values.push(a[key]);
}
alert(array_keys);
alert(array_values);
```

It returns the values as

```
My output : [abc:def] [1,40]
```

Any help on this?

Comment: You are currently just putting all keys in an array and all values in another -- the Output is actually `[abc,def] [1,40]`.

Comment: Its because JS expects every key in the array to be unique. This wouldnt work out of the box. If you change def's to 3 different keys, it works perfectly.

Comment: `var a = {"abc": 1, "def": 2, "def": 42, "def" : 40};` actually produces **Object {abc: 1, def: 40}**. How are you actually getting your array values initially?

Comment: @Maniram, can't you change the structure to this: {"abc": [1], "def": [2, 42, 40]} ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve something like what you want if you play around with your initial data structure:

Have an array of objects:

```
var a = [{abc: 1}, {def: 2}, {def: 42}, {def: 40}];
```

Set up a new object

```
var o = {};
```

And then loop over the data. For each object: if the key doesn't exist in `o`, the output object, add it and set its value to an array, otherwise just push the value of the object to the array.

```
for (var i = 0, l = a.length; i < l; i++) {
  var key = Object.keys(a[i]);
  if (!o[key]) { o[key] = []; }
  o[key].push(a[i][key]);
}
```

And you end up with an object the values of which are arrays:

```
console.log(o); // {abc: [1], def: [2,42,40] }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6qDYH/)

Comment: Hmmm, I wish this answer was updated with the new Javascript Map

Comment: You could write your own answer @AjOtto that does use `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

`var a = {"abc": 1, "def": 2, "def": 42, "def" : 40};`

This is not possible. Object keys must be unique in javascript, so you can't add 3 different items with the same key ("def"). If you define multiple elements with the same key, at least chrome will take the **last** added value.

So answering your question: With the input provided there is no way to get you Expected output.